# How to share session across server in nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, session, amazon-web-services

I want to create a stateless server, so that if any server goes down the loadbalancer can redirect the request to other servers. But if the session is created on one server and it goes down then how to persist it.I am using mysqlstore to persist my session in the database, but for each server, it creates a new record in database thus session id is not shared across different servers. So, need a mechanism to making server stateless.

Comment: By definition, a stateless application won't maintain a session.  Session is state.  Are you sure you're asking the right question?

Comment: If a server goes down you don't have to worry about the redirect. AWS ELB automatically marks it unhealthy and sends the traffic to another health server which is attached to load balancer.

Comment: Use application controlled session sticky ness http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-sticky-sessions.html#enable-sticky-sessions-application

Comment: @error2007s Session stickyness won't help the user if the instance goes down, which is what the OP is trying to solve.

Comment: I suggested Application controlled session stickiness so the stickiness will be depended upon the cookie generated from the application. So if the server goes down no cookie from that server.

Comment: @error2007s That doesn't solve the problem at all.

Comment: Ok anyways it is not the answer I am giving it is just a suggestion that I am adding in comments section, if you know the solution give it as a answer.

Comment: I see you tagged this with MySQL, but I would look into using Redis to store sessions: https://github.com/tj/connect-redis

Comment: I want to do a shared session outside the server. so that all the servers can use it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're using `express-session` because it wasn't otherwise indicated.

You're on the right track with the mysqlstore. The way to get around Node's single-threadedness here is to ditch `express-session` and instead encrypt the session data and put it into a client cookie. Then you can decrypt the session data on a GET request and validate it in your database using an isolate key in the cookie (or create a new session/cookie pair if none exist).

The most popular Node.js middleware for this is `cookie-session.` Great documentation there as well.

https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session

As a side note, since it sounds like you're at a pretty scalable place right now with multiple servers, it's worth ditching `express-session` anyways. `express-session` uses MemoryStore, which is has a known issue with memory leaks. Fine to use for smaller projects, but probably should be reconsidered for larger ones.